# WCF service concurrent calls timeout

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

WCF EF 6.0, .Net 4.5, SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here's what my service does:
1. Calls ServiceA, ServiceB for validations.
2. Calls LibraryA
3. LibraryA performs a select then an insert
4. Service calls LibraryB
5. LibraryB performs an insert
6. Service performs an insert

Now all these are accomplished within the same transactionscope [ReadUncommitted] I pass the DBContext around.

Everything works very well. Average response time is around 600 ms. Now if I introduce some concurrency, I start seeing timeouts after about 1500 calls.

I simulate concurrency using a parallel.ForEach in my client calling the service 2000 times with different data from an array. It works until about 1500 calls and after that I receive the service channel has timed out [00:00:59] secs error. But I see insertions in database which means the service is doing the job but the client is receiving a timeout.

I have the following settings in my service:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"/>
<binding name="basicHttpBinding_None" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="429496729" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="429496729" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
```

And I did read several threads here and elsewhere, tried setting my transfermode to 'Streamed', nothing worked.

Please assist.

Comment: Is your DB the bottle neck and taking longer than 60sec to respond?

Comment: Cant tell without more code, but my guess is that the database deadlocks under some rare condition. Lose the transaction scope and see if the problem goes away

Comment: @Ewan Thanks, I don't see deadlocks in the databse. I am still in a developer machine and connect to a DB server, and not sure how can I check to see if there is a long runing query.

Comment: use the  sql server profiler tool.

Comment: @Ewan Don't have access to it, let me check with a DBA. Thanks. To your other point, it fails even after I removed the transactionscope. I am closing the Client too after each call.

Comment: hmm I suppose it could still block without the transaction, but much less likely. If I think of anything else ill post.